# JDBC Optimisation of query

Tags: java, jdbc

my question is JDBC can optimise query or just the SGBD can do that, and if JDBC also can optimise which one is the best.
another question what is the difference between analyse and compiling query in JDBC?

Comment: What is SGDB?  Is it a legitimate recognized FLA for something ITRW (or IYI) ... or just a typo?  (Google doesn't help)

Comment: Jdbc is just an interface that database systems can implement. It's up to each pig those implementations to do whatever optimizations. Most will do it on the server, not client (and jdbc is just the client interface).

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how you would train a pig to do database optimization :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC doesn't optimize database queries.  A specific JDBC driver might do query optimization, but it is likely that query optimization is done by the backend database.  (Many / most worthwhile optimizations require knowledge of the tables that the JDBC driver does not have.)

> Another question what is the difference between analyse and compiling query in JDBC?

Compiling is simply parsing the SQL, resolving identifiers in the SQL source to tables, columns and so on, checking that the types of expressions are correct.

Query optimization starts with the compiled SQL and works out the most efficient way to perform the queries based on things like presence / absence of indexes and sizes of tables.